# Rails - Are saving params in sessions a generally good idea for multistep forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm generally new to Rails but have a decent understanding of MVC Architecture.

With a Multistep form, I have been saving my params to my session and at the end of the multistep form pulling the values from the session and saving to my db. I want to save the data at the end of the multistep, not throughout the journey.

An Example :-

Form 1 Controller

```
session[:user_details] = params
```

Form 2 Controller

```
@orders = Order.new
@orders.first_name = session[:user_details]['first_name']
@orders.last_name = session[:user_details]['last_name']
@orders.save!
```

Is this approach the best method given the scenario, or is there an alternate method in ruby which would be clearer?

Comment: I do not know if is the best solution to save in session but I share to you this gem [wicked](https://github.com/schneems/wicked)

Comment: Thanks Inye, I will checkout this gem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an alternate approach is to use partial updates. Instead of treating the checkout process as the buildup to one huge POST request you can create the order early and treat each subsequent step in the process as a PATCH request which updates the order with more details such as addresses or payment details.

Another approach is to use associations and use one controller for CRUDing the seperate parts of one order:

```
POST /order 
-> GET /order/1/addresses/new
POST /order/addresses
-> GET /order/1/payments/new
POST /order/payments
-> GET /order/1/confirmation
```

Comment: That would be an interesting approach Max, 
If the user falls out of the checkout process would you just use a cron to delete the user....Or would you just save the user as an incomplete user in the journey?

Comment: I would use a cron. As part of this approach you will want to add some sort of state holders to your models such as enum columns or even full blown state machines.

Comment: The biggest advantage here is that each component will only do one job instead of moshing everything into one monster controller action.

Comment: Thanks for your help Max, I'll look into developing this approach and read more about state holders. I'm also using stripe so was against using this session method in one big controller as the stripe request will already add a little load time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good approach but you have to remember to clear session when user enter the new form again. Another approach is to hide "previous form" and show "next form" via javascript. In fact all previous fields are stored in hidden fields instead of session and you have only one form, you just hide given sections so user thinks he is on the next step. At the last step you submit form and process it like standard one-step form

Comment: Thanks Dziamber, I thought about using a javascript approach to show and hide the forms, I thought it might be better a better UX approach for the user although when the form submits there might be a huge amount of errors that could be un-manageable.